# newspaper3k - get articles from HTML instead of URL

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy, newspaper3k

I'm using `newspaper3k` inside `Scrapy` parse method. I want to extract links but I don't want to fetch the website again.

Is it possible to use this:

```
newspaper.build(..)
```

with plain `html` so I can call `.articles` than?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
import httpx

from newspaper import Article

async def get_article(url):
    with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(url)

    article = Article(url)
    article.set_html(response.text)
    article.parse()
```